# Reading text files from AWS S3 bucket using Python boto3 and timeout error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, timeout, boto3

I want to read large number of text files from AWS S3 bucket using boto3 package. As the number of text files is too big, I also used paginator and parallel function from joblib. Here is the code that I used to read files in S3 bucket (S3_bucket_name):

```
import boto3
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

# ignore warnings
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

#
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', # verify=False,
                        aws_access_key_id = my_aws_access_key, 
                        aws_secret_access_key = my_aws_secret,
                        region_name = aws_region_name)
# 
resource = boto3.resource(
    's3', #verify=False,
    aws_access_key_id = my_aws_access_key, 
    aws_secret_access_key = my_aws_secret,
    region_name = aws_region_name)
)


# The Paginator
paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects')
operation_parameters = {'Bucket': S3_bucket_name}
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(**operation_parameters)

def read_s3_txt(Bucket, filename):
    return str(resource.Object(Bucket, filename).get()['Body'].read(),"utf-8")

# Read page by page and add them in text_contents
text_contents = []
for page in page_iterator:
    files = page.get("Contents")    
    # read files in parallel   
    texts = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, prefer="threads")(delayed(read_s3_txt)(S3_bucket_name, file['Key']) for file in files) 
    text_contents.extend(texts)
```

The above codes works well, however I got an error for "none" URL as below for reading .txt files in page 2. I could not find any stackoverflow or github page for this type of errors. It looks like endpoint URL is "none" for some of .txt files. My question is 1) how can I exclude reading those "none" URLs if the error related to those "none" endpoints and 2) how to optimize the code and make it fast for reading millions of records as it currently takes 25 minutes for reading 100,000 .txt files with 32GB RAM.

Your help is much appreciated!

*Error:

```
timeout                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\response.py in _error_catcher(self)
440             try:
--> 441                 yield
442 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\response.py in read(self, amt, decode_content, cache_content)
517                 # cStringIO doesn't like amt=None
--> 518                 data = self._fp.read() if not fp_closed else b""
519                 flush_decoder = True

c:\Program Files\Python39\lib\http\client.py in read(self, amt)
467                 try:
--> 468                     s = self._safe_read(self.length)
469                 except IncompleteRead:

c:\Program Files\Python39\lib\http\client.py in _safe_read(self, amt)
608         """
--> 609         data = self.fp.read(amt)
610         if len(data) < amt:

c:\Program Files\Python39\lib\socket.py in readinto(self, b)
703             try:
--> 704                 return self._sock.recv_into(b)
...
--> 102             raise ReadTimeoutError(endpoint_url=e.url, error=e)
103         except URLLib3ProtocolError as e:
104             raise ResponseStreamingError(error=e)

ReadTimeoutError: Read timeout on endpoint URL: "None"
```

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace as a text snipped, not a partial trace as an image.  Also it's possible reading 50-60 files a second is approaching the limit of the available bandwidth of wherever this is being run.

Comment: Thanks Anon, I updated and replaced text with image.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workable solution for my case. It might be some other reasons but the following changes worked for me. It looks like the error is not related to "none" url endpoint, and it is more about max_attempts in Configuration file.

1. I replaced 'list_objects' with 'list_objects_v2', and changed PageSize to 500, the problem solved for me. This change also helped with the speed, and increased the speed by approximately 1.5.

   ```
   paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
   page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=s3_bucket_name,  PaginationConfig={'MaxItems': 1000000, 'PageSize':500})
   ```
2. The other thing that I found it useful was adding the following for "timeout error".

   ```
   from botocore.client import Config    
   config = Config(retries = { 'max_attempts': 10, 'mode': 'standard' })

   #
   s3_client = boto3.client('s3', # verify=False,
                    aws_access_key_id = my_aws_access_key, 
                    aws_secret_access_key = my_aws_secret,
                    region_name = aws_region_name, 
                    config=config)
   # 
   resource = boto3.resource(
                   's3', #verify=False,
                   aws_access_key_id = my_aws_access_key, 
                   aws_secret_access_key = my_aws_secret,
                   region_name = aws_region_name,
                   config=config)
   ```

The default value for max_attempts is 5.

Other comments/answers are all welcome.